# Where to delete my Visual Studio 2013 user folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

when you first start visual studio as a new user you get a window where you have select the theme and the prefered language e.g. JavaScript. Also you don't have installed any additional plugins.

**Now my question:** Which folder I ave to delete to start this progress again for my user which already uses VS?

Comment: Tools -> Import and Export Settings lets you reset your settings back to one of the defaults. That doesn't address the plugins side of things but was that something you actually wanted to do or just a side-effect you thought you would suffer because of doing the reset?

Comment: I also would like to delete all plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well you would like to reset VS to its factory settings, but without doing a reinstallation?

In a command prompt, you can type:

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

It will do the same thing as `Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings`: rollback your settings to the defaults.
You can also type:

```
devenv /resetuserdata
```

Which will completly wipe your VS user folder in `%localappdata%/Microsoft/VisualStudio`. Note that the latter also call the first.

About your plugins, I don't know if these commands affect them, but shouldn't be an option to disable them in `Tools > Add In Manager`?